# Upload file linked with Opportunity record

Tags: apex, feeditem, files

I want to create VF custom page to upload files, which are bigger than 25mb, so i can't use Attachments. I have found out, that when i upload file from "Files" tab, i can query it by `SELECT id, FileType, Title from ContentDocument`, but i dont know how to link this file with Opportunity record. Do you have some example code for this? I think that i could link this through `FeedPostId` field, but it is deprecated.

Comment: Looks like you could create a `FeedItem` on the Opportunity record and attach the file to that post as per this question/answer http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/43765/how-can-i-create-a-chatter-file-via-apex

Comment: thanks man it works! the secret ingredient was ContentVersion object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, thanks to @AntonioManente i was able to this with this piece of code:

```
ContentVersion cont = new ContentVersion();

cont.Title = 'Title for this contentVersion';
cont.PathOnClient = 'file_' + Datetime.now().getTime() + '.txt';
cont.VersionData = Blob.valueOf('My Content in file_' + Datetime.now().getTime() + '.txt');
cont.Origin = 'H';

insert cont;


FeedItem elm = new FeedItem(Body = 'Post with related document body', ParentId = linkedRecordId, RelatedRecordId = cont.Id, Type = 'ContentPost');
insert elm;
```