# How to handle different types of attachments

Tags: attachment, document

I have a requirement that a client would like to store financial related documents and other types of documents as attachments in a record. They want to be able to be able to tell the difference without having to open attachments.

SF only allows one notes and attachments so we can't make two related lists. Besides forcing the users to use a special naming convention for attachments, are there any other ways to handle this so they can store attachments in an orderly fashion?

Comment: You are right, in our org we are using naming convention to identify what kind of file it is.
To reduce manual renaming,we have created a VF page to attach files which rename the file name automatically.

Comment: You need to migrate away from notes and attachments: Starting in Summer ’17, you won’t be able to use the Notes & Attachments related list to attach files to records anymore. You will need to use the Files related list instead. Add it to your page layouts now or sometime during Spring ’17 so your users can attach files in Summer ’17 without missing a beat.

Comment: So in moving to files you should be able to add more details - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/43765/how-can-i-create-a-chatter-file-via-apex