# How to save Renderas='pdf' in files folder

Tags: apex, email, attachment, pdf, blob.topdf

Is it possible to save a visualforce page with renderas='pdf' to the files folder so I can attacht the files to an email in lightning? Something like

```
files f = new files( FolderId = UserInfo.getUserId(), Body = pdfBlob, Name = 'pdf_file.pdf', ContentType = 'application/pdf', Type = 'pdf'); insert f;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using [`getContentAsPDF`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_System_PageReference_getContentAsPDF.htm), you can get a visualforce's page content as a pdf, regardless of the pages `renderAs` attribute.

You won't be able to perform DML on the file object directly, since its a label for the `ContentDocument` & `ContentVersion` objects. You'll need to [create one of those records](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/43765/how-can-i-create-a-chatter-file-via-apex) instead.

```
Id someID = '000000000000000';

PageReference ref = new PageReference('/somepage?id=' + someID);

ContentVersion cont = new ContentVersion();

cont.Title = 'Title for this contentVersion';
cont.PathOnClient = 'file.pdf';
cont.VersionData = ref.getContentAsPdf();
cont.Origin = 'H';

insert cont;
```

Comment: could you show an example of someUrl how to get the visualforcepage with corresponding id?

Comment: That's pretty basic stuff. I've updated the answer with some mock code. Actual implementation depends on the page and the parameters it expects, your mileage may vary.